# Suave Experimental Form select-input

Tags: f#, suave

I'm extending the tutorial at [http://vgaltes.com/suave/forms-with-suave-experimental-and-suave-forms](http://vgaltes.com/suave/forms-with-suave-experimental-and-suave-forms/)/ to support a HTML select-input/drop down list.

```
divAttr ["class", "editor-field"] [
  input (fun f -> <@ f.Name @>) [] Forms.human
]
```

The problem is that `divAttr` expects a Xml type, but `Suave.Form.input` returns a `Node`. Does anyone know how to solve this or have an example of how to do a select-input that can be added to `divAttr`?

I have looked at one example of how to do this, from the Suave Music Store book. But that seems to be outdated, and not relevant to the latest version of Suave.

I'm running Suave & Suave.Experimental 2.1.0.

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Suave and Suave.Experimental are you running?

Comment: JosephStevens Suave & Suave.Experimental 2.1.0

Comment: Did the answer help?

Comment: @JosephStevens yes, it did. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest version of Suave and Suave.Experimental (2.1.1) the code is div, not divAttr, and div expects a Node so I believe that'll fix your issue.